# There was no end point listening for WCF AuthenticationService

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7, ssl, wcf-ria-services, wcf-security

I am trying to authenticate my user logging from **windows phone 7** using
**AuthenticationService WCF** which is hosted in **IIS 7**.

*I tried it without SSL and is working fine. But I want to convert it to
https.*

The error I am getting is when I hit the call to this WCF from my WP7 emulator
is :

```
"EndpointNotFoundException"
```

However my web.config has the following details:

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <services>
     <service name="System.Web.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationService" 
    behaviorConfiguration="AuthenticationServiceTypeBehaviors">
       <endpoint contract="System.Web.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationService"  
         binding="basicHttpBinding"
         bindingConfiguration="userHttps" address="https://localhost:700/AuthenticationService.svc"
         bindingNamespace="http://asp.net/ApplicationServices/v200"/>
       <endpoint address="mex" 
      binding="mexHttpsBinding"
      contract="IMetadataExchange" /> 
     </service>

   </services>
   <bindings>
     <basicHttpBinding>
       <binding name="userHttps">
         <security mode="Transport">
           <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
         </security>
       </binding>
     </basicHttpBinding>
   </bindings>
   <behaviors>
     <serviceBehaviors>
       <behavior name="AuthenticationServiceTypeBehaviors" >
         <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
         <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"  />
       </behavior>

     </serviceBehaviors>

   </behaviors>
   <serviceHostingEnvironment
     aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

USING: AspNetSqlMembershipProvider and I am avoiding those details to make the point.

In my IIS 7, I have created an App pool and associated a self signed
certificate to the hosted WCF and in the SSL Settings options to "Require SSL
- selected" and "Ignore client certificates- checked"

I am able to browse to `https://localhost:700/AuthenticationService.svc.`

I was able to add this as a Service Reference in my phone, but when I call the
login method it is showing the error.

I have specified the end-point address and even then it is showing error.

Can anyone explain me how to debug this to get more details or any pointers to
solve "Using Authentication Service WCF via SSL"

**EDIT 1** I tried using IP addresses and the svc URL when I tried accessing
the service through browser

```
svcutil.exe https://mcname.domain.local:700/AuthenticationService.svc?wsdl
```

**EDIT 2** Tried disabling antivirus and firewalls and still no luck.

Comment: If you are hosting on IIS the endpoint address is managed by IIS hence remove the endpoint address value. Also i see that you are using Https on port 700 rather than the default 443. If that is what you want then have you mapped the SSL certificate to port 700 in IIS. Are the certificates self signed? If yes then you might get an exception that can be overridden by ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback Property  (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback.aspx)

Comment: yes its self signed and where to use this ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback?? In Wp7 it is all Async webservice calls and I dont know where to put this. I tried it with default 443 also

Comment: The ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback needs to be on the client side calling code.

Comment: @Rajesh I changed it to default port 443 and still it is showing same error

Comment: Are you able to browse on the remotehost machine locally using IE or some browser?

Comment: Yes I am able to and I can create service reference pointing to that adddress. I tried using svcutil and I got this error: HTTP GET Error
 URI: https://192.168.0.8/Authentication.svc?wsdl .Does it has somethign to do with HTTPGETENABLED key??? I want this service to be accessible only by HTTPS
  
.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18591/discussion-between-rajesh-and-rohith-nair)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Rajesh's comments, I installed the certificate in phone and it started working.

I tried all options of exporting .CER, .PFX and .P7B format and only P7B format worked for me to get it installed in phone.

The part of web.config file for enabling AuthenticationService WCF with SSL is

```
        <services>
          <service behaviorConfiguration="AppServiceBehaviors" name="System.Web.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationService">
            <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="defaultBasicHttpBinding"
              bindingNamespace="http://asp.net/ApplicationServices/v200" contract="System.Web.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationService" />
          </service>

        </services>
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="AppServiceBehaviors">
              <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
            <behavior name="">
              <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
          multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
      </system.serviceModel>

      <system.web.extensions>
        <scripting>
          <webServices>
            <authenticationService enabled="true" requireSSL="true"/>
```

Steps followed to make it work: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidhardin/archive/2010/12/30/wp7-and-self-signed-ssl-certificates.aspx

- The host name must be resolvable by the http agent via DNS, WINS,
  hosts file, etc.
- The SSL certificate must be known by a name that matches the host
  name.
- The trusted root certificate must be installed with the http
  agent, i.e. on the phone.

Installing the certificate on to the WP7 emulator phone was the trickiest part. As mentioned earlier the P7B file was hosted on the IIS and URL was accessed via emulator browser which helped me to install the certificate on phone (Sorry! I forgot the reference link).

After the installation, the endpoint issue disappeared and it started to work. As this is not a permanent solution (because everytime emulator is closed the CERT needs to be reinstalled), I  am working on http://wp7certinstaller.codeplex.com/ code to make it work when it is hosted in IIS for testing purposes.

Thanks @Rajesh for your help.